# React update view after submitting form data using react-query in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-query

I'm working on a NextJS project, and am running into an issue where my view isn't updating after a form submission. I'm using `react-query` to both fetch the data and do mutations.

I have a form called 'Add Day' which adds a day object to the database through an endpoint. But after making this update, my UI does not refresh to reflect this new object.

Here is a video that demonstrates it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHfVG.jpg

As you can see, when I refresh the page, the view updates. But I want it to update as soon as I submit the form and it is a success. Here's how my code is set up:

TripDetail

```
const TripDetailPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()

    const tripId = router.query.tripId as string

    const { data, isError, isLoading } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['trips', tripId],
        queryFn: () => getTrip(tripId),
    })

    const [tabState, setTabState] = useState(1)

    const toggleTab = (index: number) => {
        setTabState(index)
    }

    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const toggleModalVisible = () => {
        setModalVisible(!modalVisible)
    }

    const onDayAdded = () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['trips', tripId] })
        console.log('refetching')
        console.log('day was added')
    }

    console.log('new data?')
    console.log(data)

    if (isLoading) {
        return <span>Loading...</span>
    }

    if (isError) {
        return <span>Error</span>
    }

    if (!data || !data.data || !data.data.name || !data.data.days) {
        return <span>Error</span>
    }

    return (
        <div className="ml-12 mr-12 mt-6">
            <div className="flex flex-row justify-between">
                <div className="order-first flex items-center">
                    <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-slate-800">{data.data.name}</h1>
                    <Button className="btn btn-primary ml-8">Invite</Button>
                </div>
                <div className="order-last flex">
                    <Button className="btn btn-primary mr-4">Refresh</Button>
                    <Button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={toggleModalVisible}>
                        Add Day
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <AddDayModal
                    onSuccess={onDayAdded}
                    modalVisible={modalVisible}
                    toggleModalVisible={toggleModalVisible}
                    trip={data.data}
                />
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-nav" className="font-medium text-lg border-separate pb-2 border-b-2 border-gray-200 mt-6">
                <TabButton tabId={1} currentTabState={tabState} name="Plans" toggleTab={() => toggleTab(1)}></TabButton>
                <TabButton
                    tabId={2}
                    currentTabState={tabState}
                    name="Calendar"
                    toggleTab={() => toggleTab(2)}
                ></TabButton>
                <TabButton tabId={3} currentTabState={tabState} name="Ideas" toggleTab={() => toggleTab(3)}></TabButton>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                {tabState === 1 && <PlannerBoard days={data.data.days} tripId={tripId}></PlannerBoard>}
                {tabState === 2 && <h1>Tab 2</h1>}
                {tabState === 3 && <h1>Tab 3</h1>}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TripDetailPage
```

I'm calling `invalidateQueries` in `onDayAdded` which should refetch my data and update my view, but it doesn't seem to be. `PlannerBoard` is where I pass the data and is the component that renders the columns. It basically iterates through the `days` that is passed to it and renders them.

Planner Board:

```
type TDndPlannerProps = {
    days: TDay[]
    tripId: string
}

const PlannerBoard = (props: TDndPlannerProps) => {
    // ...

    props.days.forEach((day) => {
        // lots of processing, creates a data object which has the objects to make this view
    })

    const [state, setState] = useState<IData>(data) // after above processing

    // removed a bunch of code
    
    return (
        <div className="overflow-auto">
            <div>
                {day.map((day) => {
                    return <DayColumn key={day.id} day={day} />
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PlannerBoard
```

AddDay Modal:

```
type TModalProps = {
    trip: TTrip
    modalVisible: boolean
    toggleModalVisible: () => void
    onSuccess: () => void
}

const formArr: TFormField[] = [
    {
        label: 'Day name',
        name: 'name',
        type: 'text',
    },
    {
        label: 'Day date',
        name: 'date',
        type: 'date',
    },
]

const AddDayModal = (props: TModalProps) => {
    const [day, setDay] = useState<TDay>({
        name: '',
        tripId: props.trip.id!,
    })

    const onSuccess = () => {
        props.toggleModalVisible()
        props.onSuccess()
    }

    const { mutate, isLoading, isError, error } = useMutation((day: TDay) => postDay(day), { onSuccess })

    const onSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        mutate(day)
    }

    const onUpdate = (update: TFormFieldValue) => {
        setDay((prev) => {
            if (update.type == 'date') {
                return { ...prev, [update.name]: new Date(update.value) }
            } else {
                return { ...prev, [update.name]: update.value }
            }
        })
    }

    const formModalProps: TFormModalProps = {
        title: 'Add Day',
        formArr,
        submitBtn: 'Submit',
        submittingBtn: 'Adding',
        toggleVisible: props.toggleModalVisible,
        visible: props.modalVisible,
        onSubmit,
        isLoading,
        isError,
        error,
        onUpdate,
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <FormModal {...formModalProps} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddDayModal
```

The `mutate` here makes the axios call to my API which updates the db with this form data. Once we hit `onSuccess` the API call has succeeded and it call's TripDetailPage's `onDayAdded()`.

Any idea how to make my UI update when the refetch completes? Do I need to use `useState` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the expected behaviour with react-query.

You can either use `queryClient.invalidateQueries` to refetch single or multiple queries in the cache or use `queryClient.setQueryData` to immediately update a query's cached data.

You can use this directly in the `onSuccess` callback if you wish.

See [documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient).

Comment: I'm already doing `queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['trips', tripId] })` as you can see in my code, but it is not updating the view.

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from `PlannerBoard` component. As the state is not updated, it might be a logic problem. For example `props.days.forEach` will only run once since it's not in a `useEffect` or `useMemo`.

Comment: Is there a way to make TripDetail pass `props` to PlannerBoard again when the query is invalidated, forcing it to reload?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe if you move some logic from `PlannerBoard` to `TripDetail` it would work. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Or you can try to add a useMemo in `TripDetail`: `const days = useMemo(() => data.data.days, [data]);`. And `<PlannerBoard days={days} tripId={tripId}></PlannerBoard>`. That way you should have a new `days` each time `data` is updated.

Comment: I get a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')` when I try to do `const days = useMemo(() => data.data.days, [data])` after the block with `useQuery`

Comment: Yes because data is undefined for a short moment (the time for react-query to fetch the data). Add a condition: `const days = useMemo(() => data ? data.data.days : undefined, [data])`

Comment: I added `const days = useMemo(() => (data && data.data ? data.data.days : undefined), [data])` after the `useQuery` block and made it `{tabState === 1 && <PlannerBoard days={days as TDay[]} tripId={tripId}></PlannerBoard>}` but it still does not refresh the view.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you more because I too am stuck. I hope you find a solution (if so, post your solution for others to benefit from).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a fix. In my `PlannerBoard` I needed to detect the change in props through `useEffect` and then manually set the state again as:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const data: IData = createBoardData(props.days)
    setState(data)
}, [props])
```

This forces the view to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely no need to copy data from `props` into `state` in the `PlannerBoard` component. As you have found out, this is your issue, because you create a "copy" of your state. This is usually an anti-pattern, and the fix you found (syncing with `useEffect`) is not a good idea either. I have a whole blogpost series around that topic:

- https://tkdodo.eu/blog/dont-over-use-state
- https://tkdodo.eu/blog/putting-props-to-use-state

---

the easiest fix would be to move from `useState` to `useMemo`, unless you really need the `setState` method, which you haven't shown in your example:

```
const PlannerBoard = (props: TDndPlannerProps) => {  
  const state = React.useMemo(() => {
    // lots of processing
  }, [props.days])
```